# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str en una funcion

Tags: python

Tengo que crear una función que me dé una lista con varias listas para crear un tablero parecido a uno de ajedrez pero con solo las reinas como piezas, para esto hice esta función que toma en cuenta el tamaño y las posiciones de las reinas blancas y negras. El problema es que me lanza el error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str cuando ayer si me funcionaba y no he cambiado nada apropósito. No logro entender mi error agradecería si me lo pudieran explicar.

```
 def construir_tablero(talla, posicion_n, posicion_b):
    lista_listas = [["." for y in range(talla)] for x in range(talla)]
    for (x, y) in posicion_b:
        lista_listas[x][y] = "X"
    for (x, y) in posicion_n:
        lista_listas[x][y] = "O"
    return lista_listas

construir_tablero(5,["b1","d1"],["b5","d5"])
```

Este deberia ser el resultado correcto:

```
[['.', 'O', '.', 'O', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', 'X', '.', 'X', '.']]
```

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje ya te explica el error,

**TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**. (*El indice de la lista deben ser integers o slices, no strings*.)

En `construir_tablero(5,["b1","d1"],["b5","d5"])`
estás pasando strings (b1, d1, b5, d5) y luego en los **for** estás usando esos strings como indices de la lista

```
 for (x, y) in posicion_b: # acá x es "b" y "d" 
    lista_listas[x][y] = "X" # acá estás pasando "b" y "d" como índice de lista_listas
```

En este ejemplo reemplacé a,b,c,d,e por 0,1,2,3,4, sigue siendo un string, pero dentro del for lo convierto a int para usarlo como indice

```
def construir_tablero(talla, posicion_n, posicion_b):
    lista_listas = [["." for y in range(talla)] for x in range(talla)]
    for (posX, posY) in posicion_b:
        x = int(posX)-1
        y = int(posY)-1
        lista_listas[x][y] = "X"
    for (posX, posY) in posicion_n:
        x = int(posX)-1
        y = int(posY)-1
        lista_listas[x][y] = "O"
    return lista_listas

construir_tablero(5,["11","41"],["15","45"])
```

*Edit:* También nota que `range(5) = (0,1,2,3,4)` y en las posiciones le estás pasando un 5 ("b5","d5"), esto te va a dar error porque no existe el indice 5, para solucionar esto podrías restarle 1 a las posiciones dentro del **for**

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya lo tengo mas claro :)